# Is there anything wrong with using a form select element for navigation?

Tags: html, forms, navigation, user-input

I mean, I'd like to use a `<select>` list of options, and change `document.location` with javascript based on the selected option. I'd use it for product categories navigation. I already use it that way for ordering produts based on price and title.

Since it's a form element, is there anything 'wrong' doing it like this? Should I only use anchor tags maybe in lists for navigation? Or is it acceptable even to use select inputs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is anything ***Wrong*** with it; I've seen it used in some pretty big sites, but there are some things to consider.

- If the user agent has javascript disabled for some reason (it happens), the site is unusable unless you implement progressive enhancement.
- In my experience, it takes less time and effort to get a `<menu>` element  looking good. Whenever I try to style a `<select>` element to get just-the-right-look®, I usually spend way too much time banging my head against the wall, then I inevitably use the css rule `appearance:none` and pretty much start from scratch.
- If you have alot of categories, you might consider a text input with a datalist. Here is an item on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650457/html-select-form-with-option-to-enter-custom-value) about it.